# Get specific value from String

Tags: java, string

I have following String like that:`String sql = "SELECT COL1, COL2, COL3 FROM SCHEMA.TABLE";`
Now I need to get this value from String: `SCHEMA.TABLE` and this value is always changing. And also entire SQL is always changing.

How would I achieve this?

Don't know how to manipulate with different values?
This value is always after `FROM` and SQL may also have other values after `FROM`(`ORDER BY, GROUP BY...`)

SAMPLE SQL:

```
`SELECT ZGAR.ZGAR_ID, JARTI.ARTI_NAME, JZGAR.ZGAR_NAME, ZGAR.KAZG_ID, ZGAR.KZPO_ID, JZGAR.ZGAR_DESC FROM NETZGP.ZGANJEARTIKEL ZGAR LEFT JOIN NETZGP.J_ARTI JZGAR ON ZGAR.ZGAR_ID = JZGAR.ZGAR_ID LEFT JOIN NETZGP.J_ARTIKEL JARTI ON ZGAR.ARTI_ID = JARTI.ARTI_ID AND JZGAR.JEZI_ID = JARTI.JEZI_ID WHERE ZGAR.ARTI_ID = 1 AND JZGAR.JEZI_ID = 1 WITH UR`
```

Comment: You'll first have to decide which word you want to get, does it comply to certain rules (e.g. always the last word in the string?) and than you can write code that does what you want. With this information it's just impossible.

Comment: use java split function....ur SCHEMA.TABLE is always going to be after FROM.....

Comment: is the value always after FROM ? Could you give a some examples and what you expect from your program, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most succinct and reliable way is via regex:

```
String tableName = sql.replaceAll(".*FROM (\\S+).*", "$1");
```

This will also work when there's a WHERE clause after the table name.

Answer (score 1):

Try with `substring()`.

```
String result= queryString.substring(queryString.lastIndexOf(" ")+1);
```

gives the last part of the query.

If atleast FROM is there in every query

```
String[] result= s.split("FROM");
System.out.println(result[1]);
```

Comment: OP's sql is always changing so it might become `SELECT COL1, COL2, COL3 FROM SCHEMA.TABLE t`

Answer (score 0):

Use:`String table= queryString.substring(queryString.lastIndexOf(" ")+1);`

See [`String#substring()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int%29).

Answer (score 0):

If your sql query is changing frequently, you should use [`PreparedStatement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) instead of creating `Statement` many times.

```
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement("SELECT COL1, COL2, COL3 FROM ?");
String schemaTable = "<ANY_TEXT>";
p.setString(1, schemaTable);
ResultSet rs = p.executeQuery();
```

After that you can just change the `schemaTable` variable and again do `p.setString(1, schemaTable); rs = p.executeQuery();` to get new results.